# Raster library can not used in r

Tags: r, installation, raster

My R was installed in the network driver in my school computer account, it always can not find the previously installed packages. Most of the time I can successfully solve those libraries' disappear problem through reinstall those packages again, but this time, when I install the raster, there was no error, but I can not load the raster library. The error as list below:

> library(raster)

> > Loading required package: sp
> > Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in .doLoadActions(where, attach):
> > error in load action .**A**.1 for package raster: loadModule(module = "spmod", what = TRUE, env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "spmod": function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
> > In addition: Warning messages:
> > 1: package ‘raster’ was built under R version 4.0.5
> > 2: package ‘sp’ was built under R version 4.0.5

What can I do this time?
And any suggestion for the users who are using the web disk (eg.  c:/Users/sdd123/AppData/Local/R/library[default])
Thank you very much~

Comment: the error message suggest these might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Rcpp_precious_remove

Comment: Install the latest version of Rcpp: `install.packages('Rcpp')`